# async/await doesn't return the built array to the parent array.map()

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

In the following code, `expiringContentsAllBU` is populated within async/await function `getOnlyContentWhatsNewReport` which is inside the `array.map()`, but `expiringContentsAllBU` becomes empty when accessing it outside the `businessUnits.map()` function.

```
const getExpiringContents = async () => {
  let businessUnits = Object.keys(contentFulSpaces);  
  let expiringContentsAllBU = [];
  businessUnits.map( async (bu) => {
      await getOnlyContentWhatsNewReport(bu, (err, result) => { 
        if(result) {
          let expiringContentsByBU = {};
          expiringContentsByBU['businessUnit'] = bu;
          expiringContentsByBU['expiringContents'] = result;
          expiringContentsAllBU.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(expiringContentsByBU)));
        } else console.log('No expiring contents found for WhatsNewSection');
      })
    });
    console.log('result', expiringContentsAllBU);
}
```

Comment: map is synchronous method, you can't use async code in callbacks

Comment: Why are you using using `map()` for this? Why not just normal iteration?

Comment: @deathangel908 You can, but the result will be an array of promises. If you'd use `Promise.all`, that's usually even desirable.

Comment: `getOnlyContentWhatsNewReport` does not appear to return a promise, since it takes a callback. That means you cannot `await` anything.

Comment: @Bergi, I didn't say that js won't compile. in Example above map makes no sense, it's better to use forEach

Comment: map (same forEach) will not be sequential if this is what you want. For sequential await you need to use `for await of` or normal `for` with `await` inside. If you don't care about the order of requests in map you need to use `Promise.all(businessUnits.map(...`

Comment: @deathangel908 And I was saying that [`forEach` makes less sense than `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi the author didn't await the loop, nor returned anything from it.

Comment: @deathangel908 The `async` callback function returns a promise (for `undefined`, but still)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var getOnlyContentWhatsNewReport = Promise.resolve(123);

const getExpiringContents = async () => {
  let businessUnits = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];  
  const expiringContentsAllBU = await Promise.all(businessUnits.map(async (bu) => {
      return getOnlyContentWhatsNewReport.then(respBu => {
        bu.businessUnit = respBu;
        return bu;
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('No expiring contents found for WhatsNewSection');
        return null;
      });
   }));
   console.log('result', expiringContentsAllBU);
}

getExpiringContents();
```

You have to wait until the map completes and all callbacks are done. The `console.log` and the subsequent code blocks will be executed before your map completes, so

```
const getExpiringContents = async () => {
  let businessUnits = Object.keys(contentFulSpaces);  
  const expiringContentsAllBU = await Promise.all(businessUnits.map(async (bu) => {
      return getOnlyContentWhatsNewReport(bu, (err, result) => { 
        if(result) {
          let expiringContentsByBU = {};
          expiringContentsByBU['businessUnit'] = bu;
          expiringContentsByBU['expiringContents'] = result;
          return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(expiringContentsByBU);
        } else {
          console.log('No expiring contents found for WhatsNewSection');
          return null;
        }
      })
   }));
   console.log('result', expiringContentsAllBU);
}
```

Comment: But it prints `undefined`

Comment: @Prem, I don't know what you do inside `getOnlyContentWhatsNewReport`, but I have edited my answer and have posted a snippet to show how we can do it. The `return` is for inner function, you have to return the inner function response to main function to see the result.

Answer (score 1):

As [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is not aware of async functions you need to use something that is. One example is the [Bluebird `Promise.map`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) equivalent:

```
const getExpiringContents = async () => {
  let businessUnits = Object.keys(contentFulSpaces);  

  // Use Promise.map here to convert each businessUnit entry into a record
  let expiringContentsAllBU = await Promise.map(businessUnits, async (bu) => {
    await getOnlyContentWhatsNewReport(bu, (err, result) => { 
      if (!result) {
        console.log('No expiring contents found for WhatsNewSection');
        return;
      }

      let expiringContentsByBU = {};
      expiringContentsByBU['businessUnit'] = bu;
      expiringContentsByBU['expiringContents'] = result;

      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(expiringContentsByBU));
    })
  });

  // As this may contain undefined elements, remove those
  expiringContentsAllBU = expiringContentsAllBU.filter(e => e);

  console.log('result', expiringContentsAllBU);
}
```

You could flatten this code a bit more if you made `getOnlyContentWhatsNewReport` return a promise as it should instead of using a callback method. `async` won't wait on callback methods so be sure that *also* returns a promise or this code won't wait properly.

A *fully promisized* version that's refactored a litlte more looks like this:

```
const getExpiringContents = async () => {
  let businessUnits = Object.keys(contentFulSpaces);  

  let expiringContentsAllBU = await Promise.map(businessUnits, async businessUnit => {
    let expiringContents = await getOnlyContentWhatsNewReport(businessUnit);

    if (!expiringContents) {
      console.log('No expiring contents found for WhatsNewSection');
      return;
    }

    // Choosing names that match the output means you can use the destructuring operator
    let expiringContentsByBU = {
      businessUnit,
      expiringContents
    };

    // A more formalized "clone" function could help here.
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(expiringContentsByBU));
  });

  // As this may contain undefined elements, remove those
  expiringContentsAllBU = expiringContentsAllBU.filter(e => e);

  console.log('result', expiringContentsAllBU);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either change your `.map()` to a `for  loop`.

Or in your `.map()` function, return promises. Then you can call `await Promise.all(promiseArray)`

Answer (score 0):

Using async with some lodash function for sanity will help -

```js
getExpiringContents = async() => {
  let businessUnits = Object.keys(contentFulSpaces);

  let expiringContentsAllBU = await Promise.map(businessUnits, async businessUnit => {
    let expiringContents = await getOnlyContentWhatsNewReport(businessUnit);

    if (_.isEmpty(expiringContents)) {
      console.log('No expiring contents found for WhatsNewSection');
      return;
    }

    // Choosing names that match the output means you can use the destructuring operator
    let expiringContentsByBU = {
      businessUnit,
      expiringContents
    };

    // A more formalized "clone" function could help here.
    return _.cloneDeep(expiringContentsByBU);
  });

  // As this may contain undefined elements, remove those
  expiringContentsAllBU = _.compact(expiringContentsAllBU);

  console.log('result', expiringContentsAllBU);
}
```